# Obtener ultimo registro de DynamoDB

Tags: php, laravel-5, sql, dynamodb

Estoy intentado obtener el ultimo registro de x variable en una tabla de dynamoDB utilizando php. La forma sencilla que tenia era obtener los datos de los últimos 10 minutos y de esos obtener el primero.

```
//Ruta de la variable que se quiere obtener
$nameVariable = $this->convertFilter($infoVariable->variableNameDB);

//hora actual - 600 es igual 
//se definen parametros de consulta
$eav = $this->marshaler->marshalJson('{
    ":startStamp": "' . ($this->currentTime - 600) . '",
    ":endStamp": "' . $this->currentTime . '"
}');
```

Ahora, el problema de esto es que ya no puedo garantizar que los últimos 10 minutos existirán datos.

Pensé que quizás ampliando el paso pero tendría el mismo problema.

Comment: ¿No hay una columna auto-incremental o una columna que guarde la marca del tiempo en que se crean los registros?

Comment: si, existe una columna que almacena el momento de la inserción en mili segundos, que tienes en mente?

Comment: Alejo, estuve leyendo un poco al respecto. Lo que se recomienda es usar `ScanIndexForward` combinado con `true` (para orden ascendente)  o `false` (para orden descendente)  y al mismo tiempo con `limit`. Puedes revisar por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9297326/5587982), puedes [ver también aquí](https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb#decorate-query).

Comment: @A.Cedano Podrías colocarla como una respuesta, me ayudaste mucho, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación, puedes usar **[`ScanIndexForward`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)**:

> Especifica el orden para el recorrido del índice: si es verdadero
>   (valor predeterminado), el recorrido se realiza en orden ascendente;
>   si es falso, el recorrido se realiza en orden descendente.
>
> Los elementos con el mismo valor de clave de partición se almacenan en
>   orden ordenado por clave de clasificación. Si el tipo de datos de la
>   clave de clasificación es numérico (Number), los resultados se
>   almacenan en orden numérico. Para tipo cadena(String), los resultados
>   se almacenan en orden de bytes UTF-8. Para el tipo binario (Binary),
>   DynamoDB trata cada byte de los datos binarios como unsigned.
>
> Si `ScanIndexForward` es verdadero, DynamoDB devuelve los resultados
>   en el orden en que se almacenan (por valor de clave de clasificación).
>   Este es el comportamiento predeterminado. Si `ScanIndexForward` es
>   falso, DynamoDB lee los resultados en orden inverso ordenando el valor
>   de la clave, y luego devuelve los resultados al cliente.

De esto podemos concluir que si usas `ScanIndexForward` combinado con `limit` podrás obtener fácilmente el primero o el último registro según `ScanIndexForward` sea establecido a `true` o a `false`.

Para más detalles y ejemplos de código puedes consultar:

- [Is it possible to ORDER results with query or scan in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9297326/5587982)
- [Repositorio de Github: laravel-dynamodb](https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb#decorate-query)